# How to load the Spring configuration file during server startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websphere-8

I am using Websphere Application Server 8.5. My requirement is to load the Spring configuration file during server startup.

Can anyone suggest an approach other than Servlet load on startup or writing up the listener?

Comment: What is wrong with the reload on deploy behaviour?

Comment: Hi Gabor, thanks for your reply , can you please ellobrate on reload on deploy behaviour.

Comment: I have used spring-boot only with Tomcat and there, the `application.properties` file was bundled in the war file, on each deploy it was reread. What would load (and why?) the configuration if the application is not yet deployed?

Comment: Hi Gabor,Thanks for your response and ask me to look into the spring boot API, i just want to load the spring configuration file after deploying the EAR file. if you have any sample code on spring boot that could be helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are [many examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples) on their github account.